# Searching For a String Stored in a Register From Within a Function

Tags: vimscript, search, register

If I have something stored in the named register `n`, then from the normal mode hitting

`/<C-R>n`

would search for what is stored inside the register.

But suppose I want to write a function which searches for what is stored in the `n` register.
What do I do?

I tried

```
function! SearchTheDataInnReg()
   <C-R>l
endfunction
```

I get an error message:

```
E488: Trailing characters: <09><C-R>l
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From function you can access to named registers via `@`.
For explanation `:he let-@` and similars topics.
For search pattern call `search()` function.

Your code may look like this. In this example we search pattern in `l` register.

```
func! SearchTheDataInnReg()
    call search(@l)
endfunc
```

Comment: You can use `execute '/' . @l` if you want exactly the same behaviour as typing `/<C-r>l`. `search()` behaves subtly different on some points (which may be considered desirable or undesirable depending on what you're doing).